# Bash scripting - function for computing times tables

Tags: bash, shell

```
tableGenerator () {

            if [ "$1" = "**" ];then
                    i=1
                    while [ $i -le 15 ]
                    do
                            echo  "$number  $1  $i =$(( $number $1  $i))"
                            i=$(($i+1))
                    done
             else
                    i=1
                    while [ $i -le 15 ]
                    do
                            echo -n "$number  $1  $i="
                            echo  " scale=2 ;$number $1  $i " | bc
                            i=$(($i+1))
                    done
              fi
```

So in the rest of the code i have the user select the number and operator, then I call the function passing in the user input. Now my question is , can i condense this function - using the same operation to handle floats and exponents??

Comment: You should give us an idea about the possible values for the operator `$1`. I suppose the current operators like `+`, `-`, etc... and obviously `**`.

Comment: Yes sorry + , -, / ,*, **

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the reason why you want to use `bc` in some cases is to have two decimals after the decimal point. In `bc`, the exponent operator is not `**` as in `bash` but `^`.

If these assumptions are correct, I would suggest you next code:

```
tableGenerator () {

  if [ "$1" = "**" ]; then
    op=^
  else
    op="$1"
  fi

  for i in {1..15}
  do
    echo -n "$number  $op  $i="
    echo  "scale=2; $number $op  $i " | bc
  done

}
```

Comment: Yes I had floating point because of division.   Its funny but ** seems to do the same thing as ^ but obviously operates differently somehow because I replaced ** with ^ and I could simplfy the function all the way down to single while ..... |bc loop .    Anyway Thanks for the prompt. Very happy now!